# How big of a reactor a colony of a million should have for self sustaining, closed loop existance, assuming current level of technologies

Tags: science-based, physics, food, life

Suppose there is no sun, how much total energy is required to grow food, recycle air, water, and waste for a single person. I want to know how large of a reactor would be needed to keep alive a civilization of a million people who are totally isolated.

I know that humans need a certain amount of calories a day but what I don't know is what the inefficiencies are for converting joules of electrical power from a reactor into food are. Similarly, I don't know how much energy is needed to recycle waste.

Comment: When clicking on the title, I thought this question is about immortality.

Comment: Please make the title match the body. Something like"..., what is the per capita energy requirement in an isolated self sustaining community."

Comment: Energy budget for 1 human will be different than energy budget for 1 million, if there are any economies of scale in the system. Can you [edit] your post so that the question body and title are in agreement?

Comment: Questions that drastically influence energy requirements: Where is this society? Arctic, equatorial, or temperate zone?  Is it whole island, continental interior on a river, river mouth or other? How many square Km do they have can they use solar energy to grow their plants? Or is it a space based habitat or underground bunker? What standard of living? Hunter gatherer, post industrial or somewhere in between?

Comment: @Alexander : I thought it was going to be about keeping a body (with or without consciousness) technically alive in a hospital bed.

Comment: Before you can expect an answer with any detail beyond a wild guess, please try to add some more detail to you question. Is the isolated population able to access additional resources (space capsule vs asteroid vs planet)? Are you talking total indoor artificial ecosystem style energy? Grow normal food, cook and then eat it style? Or bare minimum synthesize nutrients enough to keep a human alive? A biodome style system with varied plants and animals is different from a lab with specific plants and nutrient synthesis. Both would require a host of different calculations.

Comment: Agree with Alexander.. And "ïndefinitely" would be unanswerable too ("infinite energy" ?) I propose to change the title to *"At our current technological level, what is the total amount of energy required to keep a million people alive?"* to salvage this..

Comment: Hey, vtc'ers stop vtc'ing that's a good question, which does not require a wild guess as suggested in one comment. Estimation can be given, based on average consumption of energy in countries, plus grenhouses plus recycling

Comment: @MolbOrg the question as it stands(at time of this comment) is considerably better then when it was initially posted. It's now actually a good question. Before it could not be answered without lots of assumptions.

Comment: You don't want A reactor, you want several.  What happens to your colony when their single reactor has to be shut down for maintenance?  And how efficient is your food production?  Synthetic foods, or grown under lights?  How efficient are the lights?

Comment: Great new title.. interesting question, voted +1

Comment: Reading the "duplicate", it asks about designing a reactor (what to make it from) rather than the power output required for the task. This question is about the energy requirements per-person.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your households monthly electricity bill... specifically the number of watt-hours used. Divide that number by 720 (30 days x 24 hours per day).
That will give you ONE "AVERAGE" HOUR of household power consumption.

Assuming there are four people per household, multiply that number by 250,000.
Now you know approximately how much energy a million people need.

Next, you have to multiply that number by at least 3, OR 4 to supply the city lights, the electric vehicles, entertainment centers, etc. That number might need to go even higher, lets say by a factor of 10.

That might be a rough estimate of how many megawatts to rate your reactor.

Comment: You haven't taken food production into account at all. Otherwise not bad for a first answer.

Comment: oops... maybe they're cannibals? ha ha ha! nah... good point!

Comment: Agree with the remark. I can add there will be LESS need for energy because the consumption habits on 21th century Earth can never be copied in a space colony outside the Solar system.. and there will probably be less need for personal heating facilities, like home air conditioning. Also, you'll have to take into account you'd need MORE energy, due to common needs of the community, for e.g. heat and maintaining air pressure. It's quite cold outside..

Comment: @Goodies Generally you need to get rid of excess heat in space not heat anything, vacuum is the best insulator we know of.